# How can i use two serializers in an APIView?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two serializers. I want to use HelloSerializer for POST request and SchemaSerializer for Get Request. In def get i want to list all the data in my model. How do i do that?

```
class SchemaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializes Schema"""

    class Meta:
        model = models.Schema
        fields = (  'id', 'name', 'version')


class HelloSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
```

my Views.py:

```
class HelloApiView(APIView):
    """Test API View"""
    serializer_class = serializers.HelloSerializer

    def get()

    def post(self, request):
        """Create a hello message with our name"""
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            name = serializer.validated_data.get('name')
            message = f'Hello {name}!'
            return Response({'message': message})
        else:
            return Response(
                serializer.errors,
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )
```

my models.py

```
class Schema(models.Model):
    """Database model for Schema """
    name= models.TextField()
    version = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `get_serializer_class` function like this

```
class HelloApiView(APIView):
    """Test API View"""
    serializer_class = serializers.HelloSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
           return YOUR_SERIALIZER_1
        elif self.request.method == 'GET':
           return YOUR_SERIALIZER_2
        else:
            return YOUR_DEFAULT_SERIALIZER

    def get()

    def post(self, request):
        """Create a hello message with our name"""
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            name = serializer.validated_data.get('name')
            message = f'Hello {name}!'
            return Response({'message': message})
        else:
            return Response(
                serializer.errors,
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple to do, just overwrite the `get_serializer_class` method to return the serializer class based on the request method.

```
class HelloApiView(APIView):

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method.lower() == "get":
            return MyApiControllerGetSerializer 
        else:
            return MyApiControllerSerializer
```